# Conducting a pooled winsorization

Tags: stata, data-cleaning

I am dealing with a panel data set with 917 different firms and want to winsorize my data by setting the extreme values at the level of the entire pooled sample.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is a sample of my data-set

```
date        Ret1    Ret2    Ret3     ...    Ret917
1/11/2011   3.05    3.17    27.84    ...    3.42
2/11/2011   3.12    3.19    28.08    ...    3.45
```

I tried using:

```
 winsor2 [varlist], replace cuts(5 95)
```

But evidently, this didn't work since it only deals with one `Ret` variable at a time, instead of pooling the extreme values and replacing all the  `Ret` variables.

Edit:
Cross-posted here: http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1360016-how-to-conduct-a-pooled-winsorization-using-panel-data

Comment: Cross-posted and partially answered at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1360016-how-to-conduct-a-pooled-winsorization-using-panel-data In any forum, telling people about cross-posting is polite.

Answer (score 0):

As per http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1360016-how-to-conduct-a-pooled-winsorization-using-panel-data

All that was needed was to convert the data into panel form, so that the returns are combined into a single column..